# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. React table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am getting this warning and I don't know how to solve it. I think it has to be with react-tables-2, the complete warning says this:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See..
in Cell (created by ReactTable)
in div (created by TdComponent)
in TdComponent (created by ReactTable)
in div (created by TrComponent)
in TrComponent (created by ReactTable)
in div (created by TrGroupComponent)
in TrGroupComponent (created by ReactTable)
in div (created by Tbody)
in Tbody (created by ReactTable)
in div (created by TableComponent)
in TableComponent (created by ReactTable)
in div (created by ReactTable)
in ReactTable (at CustomReactTable.js:106)
in div (at CustomReactTable.js:99)
in CustomReactTable (created by Context.Consumer)
in withRouter(CustomReactTable) (at ProductIndexComponent.js:69)
in div (at ProductIndexComponent.js:68)
in ProductIndexComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
in withRouter(ProductIndexComponent) (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at Wrapper.js:38)
in div (created by Sidebar)
in div (created by Sidebar)
in Sidebar (at SideBar.js:62)
in div (at SideBar.js:61)
in SideBar (created by Context.Consumer)
in withRouter(SideBar) (at Wrapper.js:36)
in div (at AuthenticatedComponent.js:33)
in AuthenticatedComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
in withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent) (at Wrapper.js:35)
in div (at Wrapper.js:34)
in Wrapper (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.js:28)
in Switch (at App.js:26)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:25)
in div (at App.js:24)
in App (at src/index.js:10)
```

I have this warning twice in my console, and I've checked and tried to use the keys but it is not working, does anyone know what should I do to get rid of this warning?

Edit: 
this is the render method of the general table, and then I use this component for every table I need, for example, ProductTable, and I call this component.

```
render() {
return (
  <div className='main-content'>
    {this.state.showDelete && (
      <DeleteComponent onCancelDeleteClick={this.onCancelDeleteClick} item={this.state.item} />
    )}
    <h3>{this.props.modelName}</h3>
    {this.loadAddButton()}
    {this.loadFunctionalities()}
    <ReactTable
      data={this.state.data}
      columns={this.props.columns}
      manual
      onFetchData={this.onFetchData}
      pages={this.state.pages}
    >
    </ReactTable>
    <div className="total-records-tag">{this.props.modelName}: {this.state.totalItems}</div>
  </div >
)
```

}
  }

ProductComponent render method

```
  render() {
return (
  <div className='main-content'>
    <CustomReactTable columns={this.state.columns} modelName={"Products"} />
  </div >
)
```

}

Comment: You need to provide a unique `key` to each child rendered inside an array (list). Please share your render method

Comment: Are you using a library for the table? Or you just repeat tr` tags? If so, the `key` attribute should be on the `tr`s element..

Comment: I am using react-table library, that's why I have no control over the tr and td..and so

Comment: @nacho, did  you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @ dileepkumar jami, I did but now I dont remember..I will check and if I remember I let you know

Comment: In my `column -> accessor` function, I had a `<span>` tag to format the data rendered.  I had to put a `key` separately in this to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

React optimizes by rendering only what needs to be refreshed. A loop can pour out non unique components to be rendered.
You can solve it by using the key prop.

Assume you have a list of employee objects.
Assume each employee has an id

```
employees.map(x=> <MyComponent key={x.id}/>)
```

Always use unique values for a key. Like employee id in this case. Don't use array indices.

Comment: This is a generic answer which gives an idea about how to  answer it but does not actually answer the question

Comment: OP is aware of the `key` requirement; this issue is specific to `react-table` (which normally provides list item keys itself, but doesn't appear to be doing so in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Set the **index** after the **headerGroup** and use it the **tr** tage as a key

```
{headerGroups.map((headerGroup, index) => (
    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps} key={index}>
        ......
    </tr>
))}
```

Comment: Don't use index for keys. You might be tempted to use an item’s index in the array as its key. In fact, that’s what React will use if you don’t specify a key at all. But the order in which you render items will change over time if an item is inserted, deleted, or if the array gets reordered. Index as a key often leads to subtle and confusing bugs.